# asp.net PlaceHolder usage

Tags: asp.net

I found a programmer using a place holder like this

```
<asp:PlaceHolder ID="placeHolder4" runat="server">
  <asp:Repeater ID="repeaterSearchBookResults" runat=server>
          <HeaderTemplate>Code  </HeaderTemplate>


         <ItemTemplate> Code</ItemTemplate>

        <FooterTemplate> Code </FooterTemplate>
     </asp:Repeater>
</asp:PlaceHolder>
```

In the code, he did not add any controls, he did nothing except setting visible true to the place holder.

Is there some trick that I should know about place holders, or he is just too lazy to remove the place holder and use panels!!

Comment: Hi Costa, Repeater is a server control, earlier than GridView in asp.net we have repeaters. Also placeholders act as a container so he placed repeater inside that, bcoz of the placeholders do not generates hTML

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The placeholder has the advantage that it does not render any HTML content itself; it just renders its contents. A panel, on the other hand, always wraps its contents in a (possibly unnecessary) `<div>` (or something similar, see the question linked below).

Related question: [ASP.Net: Panel VS. PlaceHolder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/483352).