# How to populate place holder on jqueryui accordin click

Tags: asp.net, jquery-ui

I have problem in loading placeholder on jqueryui accordin click. I have populated according from backend. i need to populate the place holder based on the accordin header click.

this is my html

```
<html>
<head>
    <script>

    $(function () {
        $('#login').button({ icons: { primary: "ui-icon-person"} });
        $('#showDataSource').button({ icons: { primary: "ui-icon-newwin"} });
        $('#logout').button({ icons: { primary: "ui-icon-locked"} });

        $('#login').click(function () {

            var panel = $('#loginPanel').dialog({ modal: true });
            panel.parent().appendTo($("form:first"));
        });

        $('#logout').click(function () {
            (function (event) {

            });
        });

        $('#showDataSource').click(function () {
            $('#dataSource').dialog({ modal: true, width: 1000, height: 700 });
            $('.accordion').accordion({ autoHeight: false, navigation: true, collapsible: true,
                active: false,
                changestart: function (event, ui) {
                    var dataSourceID = ui.newHeader.find('a').attr('id');
                    //var dataSourceColumn = EasyOutputWeb.Services.GetDataSourceColumns(dataSourceID, onsuccess, onError);
                    $.post(dataSourceID, function (data) {

                        //ui.newHeader.next("div").html(dataSourceID);
                        $('#columnPlaceHolder').html(dataSourceID);
                    });
                }
            });
        });
    });

    function onsuccess(msg) {
        alert(msg);
    }
    function onError(msg) {
        alert(msg);
    }

    </script>

</head>

<body>
        <div id="dataSource" runat="server">  
                <div class="divtable">  
                    <div class="headrow" id="#accordianHeight">  
                        <div class="divcol">  
                            Data Sources</div>  
                        <div class="divcol" >  
                            Columns</div>  
                        <div class="divcol">  
                            Strong Keys</div>  
                    </div>  
                    <div class="divrow">  
                        <div class="content">  
                            <div class="accordion" id="accordianHeight">  
                                <asp:PlaceHolder ID="dataPlaceHolder" runat="server" />  
                            </div>  
                        </div>  
                        <div class="content">  
                            <div id="dataColumn">  
                                test column  
                                <asp:PlaceHolder ID="columnPlaceHolder" runat="server" />  
                            </div>  
                        </div>  
                        <div class="content" >  
                            <div id="dataKey">  
                                Test key  
                                <asp:PlaceHolder ID="keyPlaceHolder" runat="server" />  
                            </div>  
                        </div>  
                    </div>  
                </div>  
            </div>  

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The first mistake here is that you use `PlaceHolder` that they [are not warp with any tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/483352/asp-net-panel-vs-placeholder)  and so jQuery can not grab them. Use `Panel` that warp with span or div your content.

Second mistake is that when the asp.net renders them the final id of each one is get from the `.ClientID` property, so the code of jQuery will be as:

```
$('#<%=columnPlaceHolder.ClientID%>').html(dataSourceID);
```

And one comment, if you do not actually add any controls on code behind on your `Panel`'s then you simple place a `<div id="columnPlaceHolder"></div>` code to write on them, and use the jQuery call as it is now (don't add the CliendID)

Comment: thanks a lot, its working. but my method not returing any result set.

Comment: thanks a lot, its working. but my method not returing any result set. This is my method var dataSourceColumn = EasyOutputWeb.Services.GetDataSourceColumns(dataSourceID, onsuccess, onError); i am calling from asmx file.   [WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
        [ScriptMethod]
        public string[] GetDataSourceColumns(string dataSourceId)
        {  //doing some operation and returing name array, i can able to see the result in onsuccess(msg) by using alert
            return names.ToArray();

Comment: @user1557020 this is a second question. Really do not understand what is this issue.

Comment: //var dataSourceColumn = EasyOutputWeb.Services.GetDataSourceColumns(dataSourceID, onsuccess, onError)   this is the method i am calling from webservice, that returns string of arrays, i supposed to bind this string of arrays to my div column "columnplaceholder".