# Nested Literals

Tags: asp.net

I have an ASP.NET website that is not passing the W3C XHTML validation.

It doesn't pass validation because I place `<div>` content into a `<asp:Label>`, and so the resulting markup looks like:

```
<span><div>stackoverflow</div></span> <!-- INVALID; DIV INSIDE SPAN -->
```

However, after replacing all my `<asp:Label>` with `<asp:Literal>`, I get errors that `<asp:Literal>` cannot be nested inside another `<asp:Literal>`.

I don't really understand how I'm suppose to be solving this, since `<asp:Literal>` sounds like it would have otherwise been exactly what I wanted.

Is the correct solution to use `<asp:PlaceHolder>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this solution

```
<div id="div" runat="server">
</div>
```

in code behind

```
div.InnerHtml = "<div>Example HTML</div>";
```

Comment: Is there anyway to pretty up the final output? The id becomes really ugly in the source; `id="ctl00_ContentBody_FormLabel"`.

Comment: div.ClientIDMode = System.Web.UI.ClientIDMode.Static;

Comment: That looks great, but any .NET 2.0 solutions? Unfortunately I have to target .NET Framework 2.0.

Answer (score -1):

Duplicate, answered in: [Using Panel or PlaceHolder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/483352/asp-net-panel-vs-placeholder)

Short answer, an `<asp:Panel>` becomes a `<div>`, so you want something like

```
<asp:Panel>
  <asp:Label .../>
</asp:Panel>
```

Comment: I don't exactly want a `<div>` either; I want nothing. `<asp:PlaceHolder` seems sorta what I want, but looking into how it works, it seems text inside a `<asp:PlaceHolder>TEXT HERE</asp:PlaceHolder>` is stored as an `<asp:Literal>` which has me scared it may not always work.

Comment: How is it that you don't want a `div`, yet you accept an answer that does exactly the same thing as I showed...?

Comment: Firstly, it wouldn't be `<div><div></div></div>` it would be `<div></div>`. Secondly, I like the lack of `<asp:control>` usage. Thirdly, it's not `<asp:Panel><asp:Label>` it would have been `<asp:Panel><asp:Panel>`.

Comment: The point was to use the panel instead of a div, and then place your label inside there. namkha87's answer does produce `<div><div></div></div>`. Finally, if you're using asp.net the whole point is to use asp controls....

Comment: namkha87's code, taken at face value, does indeed produce `<div><div></div></div>`. I don't think he meant for his `InnerHtml` property to be wrapped with `<div>` though; his solution outputs `<div></div>` with trivial changes to his example code.