# Putting the <tr> inside panel control in asp.net

Tags: html, asp.net, webforms

I am trying to put  inside the panel control in asp.net but for some reason it does not allow me to do, I am pasting my code here, I would appreciate if somebody knows this issue.

```
 <asp:Panel ID="Panel3" runat="server" GroupingText="File upload">
            <tr id="Catalog_Dept">
                <td style="width: 370px; padding-left: 2px; -ms-word-wrap: normal;">
                    Dept #: &nbsp;<span>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtDept" runat="server" Width="30px" CssClass="RegText excludeAdd txtHier"
                            onkeypress="return IsNumber(event,this);" MaxLength="3" Enabled="False"></asp:TextBox>
                    </span>&nbsp;<asp:ImageButton ID="imgDept" ImageUrl="../Images/Folder.gif" alt=""
                        class="imgAddItem imgHier" runat="server" CssClass="imgAlign" OnClick="imgDept_Click" />
                    &nbsp;<asp:Label ID="lblDeptDesc" runat="server" CssClass="RegText descriptionLabel excludeAdd"></asp:Label>
                    <br />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr id="Catalog_Supl">
                <td style="padding-left: 2px; padding-top: 5px">
                    Sup #: <span style="padding-left: 13px">
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtSupl" runat="server" Width="30px" CssClass="RegText excludeAdd txtHier"
                            onkeypress="return IsNumber(event,this);" MaxLength="3" Enabled="False"></asp:TextBox></span>
                    &nbsp;<asp:ImageButton ID="imgSupl" ImageUrl="../Images/Folder.gif" alt="" class="imgAddItem imgHier"
                        runat="server" CssClass="imgAlign" OnClick="imgSupl_Click" />
                    &nbsp;<asp:Label ID="lblSuplDesc" runat="server" CssClass="RegText descriptionLabel excludeAdd"></asp:Label>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr id="Catalog_Mfg">
                <td style="padding-left: 2px; padding-top: 5px">
                    Mfg #: <span style="padding-left: 13px">
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtMfg" runat="server" Width="30px" CssClass="RegText excludeAdd txtHier"
                            onkeypress="return IsNumber(event,this);" MaxLength="3" Enabled="False"></asp:TextBox></span>
                    &nbsp;<asp:ImageButton ID="imgMfg" ImageUrl="../Images/Folder.gif" alt="" class="imgAddItem imgHier"
                        runat="server" CssClass="imgAlign" OnClick="imgMfg_Click" />
                    &nbsp;<asp:Label ID="lblMfgDesc" runat="server" CssClass="RegText descriptionLabel excludeAdd"></asp:Label>
                </td>
                 </tr>
                </asp:Panel>
```

Comment: `<tr>` is an element of the `<table>` tag, not a panel. Try adding the `<table>` and `</table>` tags inside your `<asp:Panel>` tags

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't allow you? What is stopping you?

Comment: I cannot group them in that panel, panel goes on top of the page and control remains where they are, please see the updated question

Comment: This isn't MVC but you are looking for a placeholder, not a panel.

Comment: I know this is not MVC, but most of the mvc developers are traditional asp.net developers, I am looking for a groupbox where I can group them together

Comment: I think use newer technologies.

Comment: @MickeyMouse Only tag your question with the technologies actually relevant to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for a [PlaceHolder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.placeholder?view=netframework-4.8) not a [Panel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.panel?view=netframework-4.8). [Panel places the information inside a div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/483352/using-panel-or-placeholder). Div are [not allowed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23440362/can-we-add-div-inside-table-above-every-tr) between tr. You could always separate with multiple tbody.

Comment: How can I get a border and text on top of it? just like panel?

Comment: @MickeyMouse it seems like your table isn't needed since you only have one column. But the border can be added to tbody with css.

Comment: Thanks @the_lotus, I used the PlaceHolder for now and accepted your answer